# Установить Qt4 по умолчанию для cmake Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, qtcreator, cmake, qt4

Linux 4.10.0-38-generic #42~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 10 16:32:20 UTC 2017
В Qtcreator необходимо запустить cmake проект. Какие параметры запуска следует указать для настройки проекта под Qt4?

**P.S.**

Часть вопроса перенёс в ответ.

Comment: Судя по всему cmake не может найти qt4  а у вас стоит qt5

Comment: @Anton sudo apt install qt4* было сделано, но результат тот что выше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo apt install kde*
sudo apt-get install libc6-dev libssl-dev dpkg-dev debhelper fakeroot libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev
```

Далее использую параметр запуска cmake

```
-DQT_QMAKE_EXECUTABLE=qmake-qt4
```

Использую генератор

> Генератор для Unix (4.8.7 x64)

Источники: [раз](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-51066), [два](https://www.hiawatha-webserver.org/forum/topic/1450).

Исправляет ошибки:

```
-- Found Qt-Version 5.5.1 (using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake)
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
QT_QT_INCLUDE_DIR
   used as include directory in directory /home/alexandr/krecipes-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
   used as include directory in directory /home/alexandr/krecipes-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
   used as include directory in directory /home/alexandr/krecipes-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed

CMake Error at /usr/share/kde4/apps/cmake/modules/FindKDE4Internal.cmake:1283 (message):
  Unable to compile a basic Qt application.  Qt has not been found correctly.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindKDE4.cmake:108 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:8 (find_package)


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/alexandr/krecipes-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/alexandr/krecipes-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

а так же:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11
-- Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN
-- Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS
-- Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC
-- Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found
-- Found Qt-Version 4.8.7 (using /usr/bin/qmake-qt4)
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXau.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Looking for _POSIX_TIMERS
-- Looking for _POSIX_TIMERS - found
-- Found Automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4  
-- Found Perl: /usr/bin/perl (found version "5.22.1") 
-- Found Phonon: /usr/include (Required is at least version "4.3.80") 
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT
-- Performing Test _OFFT_IS_64BIT - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_FPIE_SUPPORT
-- Performing Test HAVE_FPIE_SUPPORT - Success
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_W_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_W_OVERLOADED_VIRTUAL - Success
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY
-- Performing Test __KDE_HAVE_GCC_VISIBILITY - Success
-- Found KDE 4.12 include dir: /usr/include
-- Found KDE 4.12 library dir: /usr/lib
-- Found the KDE4 kconfig_compiler preprocessor: /usr/bin/kconfig_compiler
-- Found automoc4: /usr/bin/automoc4
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing: LIBXML2_LIBRARIES LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindLibXml2.cmake:69 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  src/CMakeLists.txt:1 (find_package)


CMake Warning (dev) in CMakeLists.txt:
  No cmake_minimum_required command is present.  A line of code such as

    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

  should be added at the top of the file.  The version specified may be lower
  if you wish to support older CMake versions for this project.  For more
  information run "cmake --help-policy CMP0000".
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/alexandr/krecipes-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/alexandr/krecipes-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```